# SignInWithGoogle API not responding

Tags: android

I am working on trying to integrate Google Sign in API with my application. It is part of a university project. I followed the following website: https://proandroiddev.com/google-signin-compose-a9afa67b7519

But, when I try, it simply does not work. I have setup everything even in the Google Cloud APIs & Services, OAuth 2.0 Client IDs.

```
@HiltViewModel
class UserSessionViewModel @Inject constructor(
    application: Application,
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _user: MutableStateFlow<User?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
    val user: StateFlow<User?> = _user

    companion object {}
    init {
        verifySignedInUser(application.applicationContext)
    }

    fun signIn(email: String, name: String){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _user.value = User(
                email = email,
                displayName = name
            )
        }
    }

    fun signOut(){}

    private fun verifySignedInUser(applicationContext: Context){
        val gsa = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(applicationContext)
        if(gsa != null){
            _user.value = User(
                email = gsa.email.toString(),
                displayName = gsa.givenName.toString()
            )

            Log.d("User", _user.value.toString())
        }
    }
}

class SignInGoogleViewModelFactory(
    private val application: Application
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(UserSessionViewModel::class.java)) {
            return UserSessionViewModel(application) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown view-model class")
    }
}
```

**I have the following in JSON:**

```
{"web":
    {
        "client_id":"",
        "project_id":"",
        "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret":""
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

It isn't clear, how I am supposed to use this from my Android Application. If, anyone has any suggestions please share. The tutorial doesn't mention anything about this, more precisely.

**Login Screen:**

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    rootNavHostController: NavHostController? = null) {

    val coroutine = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val signInViewModel : UserSessionViewModel = viewModel(
        factory = SignInGoogleViewModelFactory(context.applicationContext as Application)
    )

    (context as? Activity)?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

    val state = signInViewModel.user.collectAsState()
    val user = state.value

    val isError = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    SideEffect {

        systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(
            color = Color.Transparent,
            darkIcons = false
        )

        systemUiController.setNavigationBarColor(
            color = Color.Transparent,
            darkIcons = false,
            navigationBarContrastEnforced = false
        )
    }

    val authResult = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = GoogleApiContract()) { task ->
        try {
            val gsa = task?.getResult(ApiException::class.java)

            if(gsa != null){
                coroutine.launch {
                    signInViewModel.signIn(gsa.email.toString(), gsa.givenName.toString())
                }
            } else {
                isError.value = true
            }
        } catch(e: ApiException){ Log.d("App", e.toString()) }
    }

    Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        content = {
            Content(
                onClick = { authResult.launch(1) },
                isError = isError.value,
                signInViewModel
            )
        }
    )

    user?.let { rootNavHostController?.navigate("Home") }
}

@Composable
fun Content(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    isError: Boolean = false,
    _signInViewModel: UserSessionViewModel
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter)
    {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.background),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
        )

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 70.dp, bottom = 0.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter,
            content = {
                Column(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(0.dp),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    content = {
                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.app_logo),
                            contentDescription = null,
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.None
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = stringResource(R.string.app_description),
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                            color = Color.White,
                            fontSize = 14.sp,
                            fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
                            lineHeight = 22.sp
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        )

        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(0.75f)) {
            Row(
                content = {
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onClick = { onClick() },
                        content = {
                            Text("Sign in with Google", color = Color.Black)
                        }
                    )
                }
            )
            Row(content = {
                Info(
                    text = stringResource(R.string.info),
                )
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**GoogleApiContract:**

```
class GoogleApiContract : ActivityResultContract<Int, Task<GoogleSignInAccount>?>(){
    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Int): Intent {
        val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("")
            .requestEmail()
            .requestProfile()
            .build()

        val intent = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, signInOptions)
        return intent.signInIntent
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Task<GoogleSignInAccount>? {
        return when (resultCode) {
            Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent)
            }
            else -> null
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I think, the issue is here. But, I have no idea how to use the `client_id` and the `client_secret` it isn't clear from the tutorial nor the documentation.

Comment: Hi, Can you share your Activity/Fragment code? What exactly isn't working for you? Do you see the user selection dialog? Are you able to choose a user?

Comment: @gioravered, **YES** I see a dialog popup with accounts on my phone, when I test it. However, when I click to select an account, nothing happens.

Comment: @gioravered, added a **LoginScreen**

Comment: Can you test if your ViewModel's signIn method is called?

Comment: @gioravered, when I click, a dialog pops up with a list of accounts, but, once I select an account nothing happens further.

Comment: @gioravered, it turns out, that `task` and `gsa` are both **null**.

Comment: Are you passing an Empty Client-ID? (.requestIdToken("")) ?
If so, this is probably the issue. Let me know if this is the case and I'll try to help.

Comment: @gioravered, no I am not. I add the `client_id` in there. **But,** maybe I am doing this wrongly, hence, why I am asking here. I am unable to find proper examples of this, except that tutorial which in itself isn't entirely clear either. However, I don't know where to pass the `client_secret` in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `.requestIdToken("")` completely resolved the issue. Wasn't required to invoke this method. Strangely.

**Note:** this `.requestIdToken("")` line, even with correct signature, it still didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I have some suggestions after reading your question and comments  i think it will clear your issue if you use requireActivity() as context in your code other than application context and if still its not working then try to create new credentials with Web client (Auto-created for Google Sign-in) and use that in your code i think iam right if not please reply

Comment: Nope. I have unfortunately resolved this issue already. Thanks for trying. Follow my latest question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73948494/sign-out-and-clearing-session-in-preferencedatastore-navigation-back-to-start-de.

Comment: can you reply what was the problem

Comment: Yes, `.requestIdToken("")` this line, even with correct signature, it still didn't work. Removing it completely resolved the issue. Wasn't required to invoke this method. Strangely.

Comment: @AlixBlaine, use that above statement in an independent answer. that way someone with similar issue won't need to read all comments if you issue was resolved.

Comment: @YılmazDurmaz, I posted an actual **Answer**.